# Problems calling Android's getSharedPreferences(); from SQLiteOpenHelper class

Tags: database, android, android-preferences

First I want to describe my situation briefly.

I have two classes, one MainClass and one DataBaseHelper class, which extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

From my MainClass I call a method in the DataBaseHelper class to open a data base. Before opening the data base I want to check the users data base version (this is important as soon as I want to update the data base and push it to the Android market). So from the DataBaseHelper class I call the following method, which is in the MainClass.

```
 public int checkCurrentDbVersion(){
        // Restore preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
        int dbUpgradeVar = settings.getInt("dbUpgradeVar", 1);
        return dbUpgradeVar;        
    }
```

I call the checkCurrentDbVersion() method from the DataBaseHelper class like so:

```
    MainClass currentDbVersion = new MainClass(); 

    int oldDbVersion = currentDbVersion.checkCurrentDbVersion();
```

As soon as the debugger runs the following line, it stops.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong? I have no constructor defined. Could that be the failure?

Best Regards
Johe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution, which I wanna share. It can be found here:

[Passing data through intents instead of constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987848/passing-data-through-intents-instead-of-constructors/988443#988443)

I forgot the **context** (I am still not 100% sure what the context is all about, but anyways...).

So to get the code working I changed it like so:

```
 public int checkCurrentDbVersion(Context context){
        // Restore preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
        int dbUpgradeVar = settings.getInt("dbUpgradeVar", 1);
        return dbUpgradeVar;        
    }
```

Call the method

```
private final Context myContext;

/*
*do some other stuff here
*/

    MainClass currentDbVersion = new MainClass(); 

    int oldDbVersion = currentDbVersion.checkCurrentDbVersion(myContext);
```

Comment: Thanks, really appreciated your question/answer.  I was calling my "getSharedPreferences" from within an activity that already had context, but I had to add "this." to the beginning (ridiculous).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution 
1.my app can not use.

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

SharedPreferences settings = new AppCompatActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, 0);
```

2.works fine in my app

```java
    public static boolean isLoggedIn(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        final SharedPreferences loggedSP = activity.getSharedPreferences(SP_name.get_Logged_SPname(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        return loggedSP.getBoolean(SP_name.get_Logged_SPkey(),false);
    }
```

to execute it in my main activity

```java
boolean a = LoginRepository.isLoggedIn(this);
```